# Removal of nickel plating on MgB2 without damaging the boride?

Tags: electrochemistry, transition-metals

I need to remove a nickel plating of a MgB2 wire without causing damage to the MgB2. I felt that electrolysis is the best method but I do not know what electrolyte to use for this. I also need to coat it with a thin layer of copper and would like to know how I can do this without oxidation to the filament.

Comment: Could you just plate Cu over the Ni?

Answer (score 1):

As you said you can use electrolysis to strip nickel. Use sulphuric acid diluted in distilled water with concentration of 10-20 % as electrolyte. Submerge the nickel-plated MgB2 after attaching it to the negative terminal of power source in the electrolyte, then submerge the cathode electrode in the electrolyte.

You can use a stirrer to speed up the process and make sure that electrodes don't touch each other.

Now switch on the power source and apply a direct current(DC). Voltage around 10 would do and make sure that you increase the  voltage slowly from the start to get to 10V.

To deposit a thin layer of Cu again use the same process. Use electrolyte as CuSO4 solution (150-250 gm dissolved per litre water), go with the range around 150 cause you want to deposit a thin layer.
Submerge the MgB2 wire as cathode and a copper electrode as anode in the electrolyte.

You can use a stirrer to speed up the process and make sure that electrodes don't touch each other.

Now turn on the power source and slowly increase the DC form 1V and reach upto 3V.

FOR REFERENCE:
https://www.smokstak.com/forum/threads/removing-nickel-plating.61941/
and NCERT

Comment: I did not downvote, but I think the answer is more credible if you cite sources for the procedures you recommend.

Comment: sure will sir .

Comment: is it any good now?

Comment: @Anjankumar Not the downvoter either, but I don't see that you've added any citations. You just made it longer and more detailed (which is GREAT), but please cite your sources.

Comment: @Anjankumar I've upvoted your answer, but please cite your sources. // From where you have researched and given your answer, that is.